# What is the method of minimum chi-square estimation?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

What is the method of minimum chi-square estimation? How is it different from maximum likelihood estimators?

Comment: Can you give some more details?  What do you mean by the method of minimum $\chi^2$?

Comment: It's minimizing the $\chi^2$ statistic. For instance, he could be fitting the probability distribution to data, so he minimizes the goodness-of-fit measure

Answer (score 4):

As the name implies, it is a method that seeks to minimize the chi-square statistic, rather than maximize the likelihood. It was advocated a long time ago  [in a paper by Berkson](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2240587?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Asymptotically  it is equivalent to the MLE, although in small samples it may be different.